# HTML,PHP select filter

Tags: php, html, select

I have a small problem. I can't get this to filter date.
I don't know if I'm missing something but I can't get it to filter ZSC_b_date
I'm not a pro programmer but still. Looking for help. Thanks.

This is the HTML code.

```
<form method="get" action="">
<select id="training_session" name="wb btn">
<option value="">Date</option>
<option value="April">April</option>
<option value="May">May</option>
<option value="June">June</option>
<option value="July">July</option>
<option value="August">August</option>
<option value="September">September</option>
<option value="October">October</option>
<option value="November">November</option>
</form>
<input type="submit" value="Filter">
```

PHP code

```
    array(
        'training_partner' => true,
        'trainer_id' => 'alves',
        'trainer_name' => 'Luciano Alves',
        'training_company_link' => '#unirede',
        'training_company_name' => 'Unirede Soluções Corporativas',
        'city_country_link' => 
        'city_country_name' => 'Porto Alegre, Brazil',
        'training_language' => 'Portuguese',
        'ZCS_b_date' => '24 November 2014',
        'ZCS_e_date' => '26 November 2014',
        'ZCS_link' => 
        'ZLE_b_date' => '27 November 2014',
        'ZLE_e_date' => '28 November 2014',
        'ZLE_link' => 
    ),
);

if (isset($_GET['lang']) && $_GET['lang']) {
     foreach ($training_sessions as $key => $session) {
        if ($session['training_language'] !== $_GET['lang']) {
            unset($training_sessions[$key]);
        }           
     }
}
```

Comment: Whats your question/problem?

Comment: What do you mean by 'filter'? What are you trying to achieve here?

Comment: `'ZCS_link' => ` is not been given a value. Probably your loop is terminating at that.

Comment: I have a html dropdown select. What im trying to do is to filter out selected date. For example if i chose november it leaves only november on the page. I don't know if im explaining it right

Comment: ZSC_link - i removed the links so that no one would see them.

Comment: @user3480148 Do you mean when you select `november` from the dropdown it should be removed? Please be more clear.

Comment: what i mean example: is that i have list of dates
August
September
October
November
December

If i select november it leaves only november and removes all other dates.

Comment: @user3480148 So summarizing, if the user selects `november` and submits, you want to unset all date values in the array that do not have `november`  correct?

Comment: yes thats what im looking for.

Comment: my language filtering works perfect. But i dont get it why date wont.

Comment: lang is just an name how i filter selection. I could raplace it with anything else still would work ofcourse if i change to same name in html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, several things:

Avoid using space in `name` attribute, so we are going to change it to:

```
<select id="training_session" name="wb_btn">
```

Give your submit button a name and place it **inside the `<form></form>` tags**

```
<input type="submit" name="filter_submit" value="Filter">
```

Now for your PHP:

```
if (isset($_POST['filter_submit']) && isset($_GET['wb_btn']) && $_GET['lang']!='') {
     foreach ($training_sessions as $key => $session) {
         foreach($session as $k=>$v){

            //this if checks for the date only in these keys,
            //you can remove it if you want to check for all keys
            if($k=='ZCS_b_date' || $k=='ZCS_e_date' || $k=='ZLE_b_date' || $k=='ZLE_e_date')
            {
               //e.g., check if 'december' is present in string '28 November 2014'
               //it would be false, so remove it
                if(stripos($v,$_GET['lang'])==false){ 
                     unset($training_sessions[$key][$k]);
                }
            }
        } 
    }
}
```

**[Demo](https://eval.in/129215)**

#### Additional:

> I have a question now how do i make it without filter button, so that
>   it would work only onclick. Should i use javascript?

Yes, you can do this with simple javascript using the `onchange` element of `<select>` tag such as:

```
<select id="training_session" name="wb_btn" onchange="this.form.submit()">
```

Comment: So i did some changes

    <option value=""<?php if($_GET['date'] === '') echo 'selected' ?>>Date</option>

And here

  if (isset($_GET['date']) && $_GET['date']) {
   foreach ($training_sessions as $key => $session) {
   if (date('F', strtotime($session['ZCS_b_date'])) !== $_GET['date']) {
    unset($training_sessions[$key]);

Thanks for help, i did some thinking and now it all works. I just changed date format. I have a question now how do i make it without filter button, so that it would work only onclick. Should i use javascript?

Comment: sorry my rep is too lov and comment section here are weird.

Answer (score 2):

"I Can Has Cheezburger" is right, your array isn't written properly. You should use an empty string if you don't want anything for "ZCS_link" (although I don't understand why you would want to do that). And you forgot to put a coma at the end of that line, so PHP is very confused now ;)
Is your debugger activated?

Also, you wrote the following condition:

```
isset($_GET['lang'])
```

But I can't see any element called **lang** in your HTML, so I assume that this condition is never true, so PHP won't run your validation.

Change

```
<select id="training_session" name="wb btn">
```

to

```
<select id="training_session" name="lang">
```

that way PHP knows that $_GET['lang'] is the value provided for your drop-down.

Comment: fixed it all but what should i add here?

if ($session['training_language'] !== $_GET['lang']) so that i would filter out only ZCS_b_date. This line was before for language filtering. And it works well. But I cant get it right for date filters.

Comment: If you are using 'lang' for language filtering, you must take it from somewhere. Can you tell my where it comes from ?


Quick question as well: where do you get your $training_sessions variable from ?
I don't see any $_GET["wb_btn"] anywhere, and that's what I would have used (with some sanitation for security of course).

Comment: I fixed it, check the comment i wrote to I can has cheezburger

Comment: Yep, seen that comment, happy that your problem is fixed :)